# In plotly, how do you retrieve the camera position of the plot after the user has interacted with it?

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

The following code creates an interactive plotly image of biased samples on a surface of a unit sphere. I know I can adjust the initial angle of the camera within `layout`. Is there a way to get the camera angle after the user has interacted with `p_naive`? I want to show the camera angle where the user can clearly see the clustering of points at the poles.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

n <- 1500
r <- 1

theta_est = runif(n, min = 0, max = pi)
phi_est = runif(n, min = 0, max = 2 * pi)

x_est_naive <- r * sin(theta_est) * cos(phi_est)
y_est_naive <- r * sin(theta_est) * sin(phi_est)
z_est_naive <- r * cos(theta_est)

p_naive <- plot_ly(
  x = x_est_naive,
  y = y_est_naive,
  z = z_est_naive,
  alpha = 0.9,
  type = "scatter3d",
  mode = "markers",
  size = 0.005,
) %>% 
  layout(title = "Naive sampling on Sphere",
         scene = list(camera = list(eye = list(x = 1.25, y = 1, z = 1))))
p_naive
```